# Long html table loses its background image

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have about 7500 (short) text lines in a table cell.
The table looses its background image on about 1800th line.
Is there a limit about the table's length?
Text in the cell stays visible till end, but without background.
Table is named #story.

```
#story{
    margin-top:15px;
    border:medium ridge #FFF;
    border-radius:9px;
    background-image:url(img/back01.jpg);
    }
```

Also tried:

```
    background: url("img/back01.jpg") repeat; // without result
    background-color:#FFF; // this works along the whole table.
}
```

Comment: can you show working code or fiddle so we can easily identify where the problem exactly and help you out.

Comment: Do you want to stretch the background image to fit the table size?

Comment: I changed this line `background: url("img/back01.jpg") repeat;` into `background: url("img/back01.jpg") fixed repeat;` and it works. But, don't know why ? Thanks to everyone. Let's say - solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing your problem:

**html:**

```
<table id="story"><tr><td id="content"></td></tr></table>
```

**js:**

```
for(var i=1; i < 3000; i++) {
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    line.innerHTML = "line " + i;
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(line);
 }
```

**css:**

```
#story{
    margin-top:15px;
    border:medium ridge #FFF;
    border-radius:9px;
    background-image:url(http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
    }​
```

I had that working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zTYH/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I tested the same code as palako and worked fine for me too

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
        #story{
    margin-top:15px;
    border:medium ridge #FFF;
    border-radius:9px;
    background-image:url(back01.jpg);
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="story"> 
         <?php 
         $z="";
         echo "<tr><td>";
         for($i=0; $i<8000; $i++)
         {
         $z = $z.$i."\n</br>";
         }
        echo $z."</td></tr>";            
         ?>
        </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```